# Visual Studio - Multiple definitions when building project

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have inherited an old VB .NET **4.0** web forms project that I need to modify but am unable to compile as .NET 4.0 is not on my dev PC and I've been un-successful trying to install as I already have 4.8. I changed the target framework in the build properties to 4.8 but now when I try to build I get a 'lot' of errors stating multiple definitions of various methods in files that doesn't exist until build time.

Example error:
'Public Sub New()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.      C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4eb1a3c1\e4ccd260\App_Code.4b4vinsp.10.vb 35

Tried downgrading to 3.5, tried using 4.6 but to no avail

Comment: Can you uninstall 4.x, install 4.0 then reinstall 4.x?  Other than that, maybe best option is to upgrade it to 4.8 and deal with the errors

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I couldn't get 4.0 to install, so I have updated it to 4.8 and these are the errors I'm trying to deal with.

Comment: The issue seems to be when compiling the .XSD files (I have 15 of them) multiple App_Code files are being generated in the temp build folder, one for each of the XSD's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the generated classes from the .XSD files have the same name or conflicting names. Consider renaming the classes to have unique names across the XSD files.

Try separate the XSD Compilation instead of compiling all the .XSD files together.

Comment: I found a copy of one of the xsd files that had a completely different filename but when looking at the xml, the contents were that same as another file and therefore causing the duplication.